# Java compare string with substring

Tags: java, arrays, substring

I was having some problem when trying to compare strings in Java.

Example of list of words to be compared:

```
angry, berry, you, young, your, apple, orange, yeast
```

When user entered 'y' character, the results I am getting:

```
angry, berry, you, young, your, yeast
```

By right it supposed to return these only:

```
you, young, your, yeast
```

The next time when the user entered 'you', the 'yeast' should be filtered out.

Here is my code:

```
for (String v : words) {
        if (v.toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())){
            System.out.print("MATCHING WORDS " + v);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `startsWith()` instead of `contains()`.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (String v : words){
    String word = v.toLowerCase();
    if(word.substring(0,1).equals(input.toLowerCase())){
        System.out.print("MATCHING WORDS " + v);
    }
}
```

Comment: @guest176969 Thanks so much for what? This will not even compile.

Comment: Still will not compile. There's no such method as `String.lowerCase()`.

Comment: Java is not Python. You can't get the individual characters from a String with the same syntax you use to get values from an array.

Comment: Nope there is also no method  `String.LowerCase()`

Comment: Now you have a solution that compiles, but that will only work if the user enters only one character.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yup, there isn't. Use toLowerCase()

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen that is because it is specific to the question. I am only taking the first letter of the string with substring(0,1).

Comment: It's not specific to the question, it's only used as an example. You should be doing `substring(0, input.length())`. Well, actually you should just be using `startsWith()`, as in the accepted answer that was given half an hour ago.